# Charts in SwiftUI Fatal error: Array index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift

Tags: charts, swiftui, swift5

I have set up Charts in SwiftUI and whenever I touch the chart I get this error:

> Fatal error: Array index out of range: file
> Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift

Which points me to this line in Charts:

```
return entries[position]
```

Here is my code for the UIRepresentable Chart.

```
struct Bar:UIViewRepresentable {
    var entries : [BarChartDataEntry] = [
        BarChartDataEntry(x: 1, y: 1)
        , BarChartDataEntry(x: 2, y: 1)
    ]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> BarChartView {
        let chart = BarChartView()
        chart.data = addData()
        return chart
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: BarChartView, context: Context) {
        
        uiView.data = addData()
        uiView.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    
    
    func addData() -> BarChartData
    {
        let data = BarChartData()
        let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        dataSet.colors = [NSUIColor.green]
        dataSet.label = "My Set"
        
        data.append(dataSet)
        return data
    }
    
  typealias UIViewType = BarChartView
    
    
}
```

For some reason it is sending a position of 2 and then I'm getting the array out of index.
Why is sending the wrong index?
It should really allow me touch the bar in the chart without any error.
Has anyone else dealt with this and came up with a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have been looking in the function "open override func entryIndex". The error has something to do with how charts detects the touch and determines what value it is closest to by rounding up or down or finding the closest value.

Answer (score 0):

Install Charts using the cocoapods then the selection of the Bars in the BarChart works fine.

```
 struct Bar:UIViewRepresentable {
    var entries : [BarChartDataEntry]
   
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> BarChartView {
        let chart = BarChartView()
        return chart
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: BarChartView, context: Context) {
        uiView.data = addData()
        uiView.notifyDataSetChanged()
        
    }
    
    
    func addData() -> BarChartData
    {
        let data = BarChartData()
        let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries)
        dataSet.colors = [NSUIColor.green]
        dataSet.label = "My Set"
        data.addDataSet(dataSet)
        return data
    }
    
  typealias UIViewType = BarChartView
  
}
```